# Serializando e Desserializando objetos Json com C#

Tags: c#, .net

Considere o JSON abaixo

```
{
  "atividade_principal": [
    {
      "text": "Atividades de televisão aberta",
      "code": "60.21-7-00"
    }
  ],
  "data_situacao": "03/11/2005",
  "nome": "GLOBO COMUNICACAO E PARTICIPACOES S/A",
  "uf": "RJ",
  "telefone": "(21) 2540-2623",
  "atividades_secundarias": [
    {
      "text": "Reprodução de vídeo em qualquer suporte",
      "code": "18.30-0-02"
    },
    {
      "text": "Portais, provedores de conteúdo e outros serviços de informação na internet",
      "code": "63.19-4-00"
    },
    {
      "text": "Agenciamento de espaços para publicidade, exceto em veículos de comunicação",
      "code": "73.12-2-00"
    },
    {
      "text": "Programadoras",
      "code": "60.22-5-01"
    }
  ],
  "qsa": [
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "CARLOS HENRIQUE SCHRODER"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "JORGE LUIZ DE BARROS NOBREGA"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "ROSSANA FONTENELE BERTO"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "ALI AHAMAD KAMEL ALI HARFOUCHE"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "WILLY HAAS FILHO"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "JUAREZ DE QUEIROZ CAMPOS JUNIOR"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "SERGIO LOURENCO MARQUES"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "MARCELO LUIS MENDES SOARES DA SILVA"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "ANTONIO CLAUDIO FERREIRA NETTO"
    },
    {
      "qual": "10-Diretor",
      "nome": "CRISTIANE DELECRODE LOPES SUT RIBEIRO"
    }
  ],
  "situacao": "ATIVA",
  "bairro": "JARDIM BOTANICO",
  "logradouro": "R LOPES QUINTAS",
  "numero": "303",
  "cep": "22.460-901",
  "municipio": "RIO DE JANEIRO",
  "abertura": "31/01/1986",
  "natureza_juridica": "205-4 - Sociedade Anônima Fechada",
  "fantasia": "GCP,TV GLOBO, REDE GLOBO, GLOBO.COM, SOM LIVRE",
  "cnpj": "27.865.757/0001-02",
  "ultima_atualizacao": "2016-11-21T09:10:20.052Z",
  "status": "OK",
  "tipo": "MATRIZ",
  "complemento": "",
  "email": "",
  "efr": "",
  "motivo_situacao": "",
  "situacao_especial": "",
  "data_situacao_especial": "",
  "capital_social": "6408935530.37",
  "extra": {}
}
```

Classes a ser serializada

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ITSolution.Web.JSON
{
    [DataContract]
    public class DataContractEmpresa
    {

        [DataMember]
        public string[] atividade_principal { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime data_situacao { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string nome { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string uf { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string telefone { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string[] atividades_secundarias { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string[] qsa { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string situacao { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string bairro { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string logradouro { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string numero { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string cep { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string municipio { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string abertura { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string natureza_juridica { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string fantasia { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string cnpj { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ultima_atualizacao { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string tipo { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string complemento { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string efr { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string motivo_situacao { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string situacao_especial { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string data_situacao_especial { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string capital_social { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string extra { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Desserializando:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace ITSolution.Web.JSON
{
    public static class JSONHelper
    {
        public static string GetJSONString(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request =
                (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(
                    stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        public static T GetObjectFromJSONString<T>(
            string json) where T : new()
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
                    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }
        }

        public static T[] GetArrayFromJSONString<T>(
            string json) where T : new()
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
                    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T[]));
                return (T[])serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aplicando

```
string url = @"https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/27865757000102";
var json = JSONHelper.GetJSONString(url);    
var r = JSONHelper.GetObjectFromJSONString<DataContractEmpresa>(json);
```

Exceção jogada

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
>
> Additional information: Houve um erro ao desserializar o objeto do tipo ITSolution.Web.JSON.DataContractEmpresa. Espera-se elemento End 'item' no namespace ''. Encontrado elemento 'text' do namespace ''.`

O problema está na serialização, sou iniciante e nunca mexi com JSON, como faço para contorna esse erro?

Comment: Se você não sabe como fazer uma (de)serialização, por que não usa algo pronto como o [**JSON.NET**](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)? Te garanto que ele é bem mais completo e fácil de usar do que essa classe helper aí.

Comment: O problema,acredito eu, sejam as coleções `atividades_secundarias` e `csa`. No JSON são coleções de objetos, já no c# é um array de `string`s...

Comment: O que tem na chave extra???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A resposta @Randrade é melhor forma de resolver o seu problema, só quero complementar que se for utilizar o pacote [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/8.0.3), pode renomear os campos da classe colocando nomes mais sugestivos, com a configuração do [JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm), exemplo:

```
public abstract class Modelo
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Qsa
{
    [JsonProperty("qual")]
    public string Qual { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class AtividadePrincipal : Modelo
{
}
```

---

```
public class AtividadesSecundarias : Modelo
{
}
```

---

```
public class Extra
{    
}
```

---

```
public class Consume
{           
    [JsonProperty("atividade_principal")]
    public List<AtividadePrincipal> AtividadePrincipal { get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("atividades_secundarias")]
    public List<AtividadesSecundarias> AtividadesSecundarias { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data_situacao")]
    public string DataSituacao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("uf")]
    public string Uf { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("qsa")]
    public List<Qsa> Qsa { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("situacao")]
    public string Situacao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bairro")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("logradouro")]
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numero")]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cep")]
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("municipio")]
    public string Municipio { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("abertura")]
    public string Abertura { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("naturezaJuridica")]
    public string NaturezaJuridica { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fantasia")]
    public string Fantasia { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cnpj")]
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ultima_atualizacao")]
    public DateTime UltimaAtualizacao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tipo")]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("complemento")]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("efr")]
    public string Efr { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("motivo_situacao")]
    public string MotivoSituacao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("situacao_especial")]
    public string SituacaoEspecial { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data_situacao_especial")]
    public string DataSituacaoEspecial { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("capital_social")]
    public decimal CapitalSocial { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extra")]
    public Extra Extra { get; set; }
}
```

isso é um exemplo completo, mas com a intenção de complemento pela serialização do nome para um determinado propriedade da sua classe.

Como utilizar?

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Consume>(json);
```

dessa forma, server para os dois processos (*Serializar e Deserializar*), mantendo o *padrão de nomes*.

<sub>**Observação:** o `Extra` ficou somente uma classe, não tem como saber o que tem dentro dela, se souber especifique na sua pergunta para complementar a resposta</sub>

Comment: Ja respondeu minha segunda pergunta. Extremamente grato pela sua resposta. Muito obrigado !

Answer (score 5):

Como dito nos comentários, o seu problema está no "Mapeamento dos objetos". Em resumo, você precisa especificar a forma que o objeto será "desserializado".

Alguns casos são complexos mesmo, e utilizar uma ferramenta como o [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) ajuda muito neste processo. Ele gera o Modelo de acordo com o json inserido.

Mas, basta alterar sua classe para isso que funcionará o seu código:

```
public class AtividadePrincipal
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
    }

    public class AtividadesSecundaria
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Qsa
    {
        public string qual { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
    }

    public class Extra
    {
    }

    public class DataContractEmpresa
    {
        public List<AtividadePrincipal> atividade_principal { get; set; }
        public string data_situacao { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string uf { get; set; }
        public string telefone { get; set; }
        public List<AtividadesSecundaria> atividades_secundarias { get; set; }
        public List<Qsa> qsa { get; set; }
        public string situacao { get; set; }
        public string bairro { get; set; }
        public string logradouro { get; set; }
        public string numero { get; set; }
        public string cep { get; set; }
        public string municipio { get; set; }
        public string abertura { get; set; }
        public string natureza_juridica { get; set; }
        public string fantasia { get; set; }
        public string cnpj { get; set; }
        public string ultima_atualizacao { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string tipo { get; set; }
        public string complemento { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string efr { get; set; }
        public string motivo_situacao { get; set; }
        public string situacao_especial { get; set; }
        public string data_situacao_especial { get; set; }
        public string capital_social { get; set; }
        public Extra extra { get; set; }
    }
```

No demais, caso queira utilizar o [JSON.Net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json), basta alterar sua linha para isso após instalar o pacote:

```
var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContractEmpresa>(json);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo post ! Foi de grande ajuda !

Comment: Esse site que tu passou é uma mão na roda!

Comment: Olá @AndreyHartung, tem um outro site chamado [quicktype](https://quicktype.io/?l=cs&r=json2csharp) que acho mais completo. Mas, fico feliz em ter ajudado.