# Deserialize JSON com Restsharp e com JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, restful

Estou com dificuldade em deserializar um JSON. Estou recebendo o seguinte conteúdo:

```
"response":{
    "account":{
        "name":"Evandro Teste",
        "owners":[],
        "creationDate":"2017-07-07T07:18PDT",
        "city":"Guarulhos",
        "description":"",
        "state":"São Paulo",
        "accountId":45,
        "lastUpdated":"2017-07-07T07:18PDT",
        "phone":"+55111231233",
        "country":"",
        "parentId":-1,
        "industry":"Teste",
        "address":"Rua Teste",
        "relationshipUrls":{
            "owners":"http://localhost/v1/object/account/45/owners",
            "attachments":"http://localhost/v1/object/account/45/attachment",
            "comment":"http://localhost/v1/object/account/45/comment",
            "contactlog":"http://localhost/v1/object/account/45/contactlog",
            "historylog":"http://localhost/api/v1/object/account/45/historylog"
        }
    }
},
"status":{
    "success":true,
    "detail":{}
}
```

Meu problema é como faço para deserialize esse JSON deixando de lado o response. Ou seja, preciso criar um objeto do tipo Account, ignorando o response(Que retorna no Json).

Estou usando o Restsharp e tentando fazer o mesmo usando também o JavaScriptSerializer.

Segue abaixo minha entidade:

```
public class Account
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string creationDate { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public int accountId { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string mapQuest { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    public string googleSearch { get; set; }
    public string linkedInSearch { get; set; }
    public string industry { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string AcctType { get; set; }
    public string websiteURL { get; set; }
    public string zipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: o que você tentou? quais são os problemas ou dificuldades encontradas? Forneça mais detalhes, por favor.

Comment: Opa, desculpe. O meu problema é converter o JSON que retornou que está ali em cima no objeto Account. No retorno da chamada do API o objeto.Data está vazio, entretanto o objeto Content contem o JSON.

Estou tentando por exemplo:

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var teste = js.Deserialize<Account>(response.Content);
            var teste2 = js.Deserialize<Response>(response.Content);
Mas quando faço isso o meu objeto "teste" e "teste2" está retonando vazio, mas não da erro.
Tentando usar RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer a mesma coisa

Comment: Evandro e ai a resposta deu certo?

Comment: Deu sim.. Obrigado. Como faço para finalizar esse tópico?

Answer (score 1):

Quando se tem um chave, e dentro delas outras, a melhor forma na minha visão é fazer o mesmo layout de classes seguindo a premissa de nomes e com isso extraindo de maneira padrão o que lhe foi retornado, um exemplo disso seria a construção sequencial das classes que nesse caso respeita os nomes de cada item contido no `json`, ***exemplo***:

```
public class Account
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string creationDate { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public int accountId { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string mapQuest { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int parentId { get; set; }
    public string googleSearch { get; set; }
    public string linkedInSearch { get; set; }
    public string industry { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string AcctType { get; set; }
    public string websiteURL { get; set; }
    public string zipCode { get; set; }
    public RelationshipUrls relationshipUrls { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Status
{
    public bool success { get; set; }    
}
```

---

```
public class RelationshipUrls
{
    public string owners  { get;set;}
    public string attachments { get;set;}
    public string comment  { get;set;}
    public string contactlog  { get;set;}
    public string historylog { get;set;}      
}
```

---

```
public class Response
{
    public Account account { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Result
{        
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
}
```

e o seu código principal para extrair essas informações, ***exemplo***:

```
string value = File.ReadAllText("base.json");
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Result r = js.Deserialize<Result>(value);
```

dentro dessa variável `r` possui a sequencia lógica desse `json` em classes de objetos. Se precisar gerar o mesmo `json` já tem o layout montado, só preencher e mandar gerar.

Também pode ser utilizado o pacote [JSON.Net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) como demostrado na [pergunta e respostas SO<sub>pt</sub>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168348/serializando-e-desserializando-objetos-json-com-c).

***Referencias***

- [Quick JSON Serialization/Deserialization in C#](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c)
- [Classe JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.90).aspx)