# Dúvida ao deserializar objetos JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, api, rest

Estou deserializando o JSON abaixo, e gostaria de saber, se preciso criar uma classe com todos atributos relacionado a esse JSON, ou posso apenas criar com os atributos que necessito usar?

Estou indo pelo caminho certo? Gostaria de opiniões sobre consumir API's, pois é a primeira vez que utilizo a tecnologia.

> JSON

```
[
   {
      "name":"Brazil",
      "topLevelDomain":[
         ".br"
      ],
      "alpha2Code":"BR",
      "alpha3Code":"BRA",
      "callingCodes":[
         "55"
      ],
      "capital":"Brasília",
      "altSpellings":[
         "BR",
         "Brasil",
         "Federative Republic of Brazil",
         "República Federativa do Brasil"
      ],
      "region":"Americas",
      "subregion":"South America",
      "population":206135893,
      "latlng":[
         -10.0,
         -55.0
      ],
      "demonym":"Brazilian",
      "area":8515767.0,
      "gini":54.7,
      "timezones":[
         "UTC-05:00",
         "UTC-04:00",
         "UTC-03:00",
         "UTC-02:00"
      ],
      "borders":[
         "ARG",
         "BOL",
         "COL",
         "GUF",
         "GUY",
         "PRY",
         "PER",
         "SUR",
         "URY",
         "VEN"
      ],
      "nativeName":"Brasil",
      "numericCode":"076",
      "currencies":[
         {
            "code":"BRL",
            "name":"Brazilian real",
            "symbol":"R$"
         }
      ],
      "languages":[
         {
            "iso639_1":"pt",
            "iso639_2":"por",
            "name":"Portuguese",
            "nativeName":"Português"
         }
      ],
      "translations":{
         "de":"Brasilien",
         "es":"Brasil",
         "fr":"Brésil",
         "ja":"ブラジル",
         "it":"Brasile",
         "br":"Brasil",
         "pt":"Brasil",
         "nl":"Brazilië",
         "hr":"Brazil"
      },
      "flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/bra.svg",
      "regionalBlocs":[
         {
            "acronym":"USAN",
            "name":"Union of South American Nations",
            "otherAcronyms":[
               "UNASUR",
               "UNASUL",
               "UZAN"
            ],
            "otherNames":[
               "Unión de Naciones Suramericanas",
               "União de Nações Sul-Americanas",
               "Unie van Zuid-Amerikaanse Naties",
               "South American Union"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

> Classe com os atributos que preciso.

```
public class APIRestPaises
{
    public string NativeName { get; set; }
    public string Alpha3Code { get; set; }
}
```

> Lendo a API

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var jsonResponse = client.DownloadString(@"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIRestPaises>(jsonResponse);
}
```

Comment: Você está consumindo e está retornando os dados corretamente?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, Sim , está retornando os dados corretamente, só estou com problema ao deserealizar o JSON

Comment: Ou seja, você está com problema nessa linha `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIRestPaises>`???

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, Eu fiz exatamente o que nosso amigo ali embaixo disse, estou recebendo os dados corretamente, mas meu problema está sendo quando deserealizo o JSON, ou seja, criei minha classe apenas com os atributos que preciso, ai ele da o seguinte abaixo, agora minha dúvida é, como faço para deserealizar apenas os atributos que preciso, posso estar errando em alguma coisa.

Comment: ERRO: Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Projeto.ERP.Desktop.APIRestPaises' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: Nicolar e ai deu certo?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, posso só tirar uma última dúvida ?

Comment: Minha dúvida é o seguinte, vamos supor que tenho um cadastro de produtos e estou sempre atualizando meus cadastrado de produtos via uma API de produtos de alguma empresa, como eu faria essa atualização de registros, ou seja, colocar em meu cadastros as atualizações ou inserções de novos produtos, eu teria que percorrer tudo isso e verificar as diferenças ? Fiquei nessa dúvida de onde fazer essa chamada da API, pois fica custoso sempre ficar chamando esse metodo correto ?

Comment: A codificação é normal, a empresa vai documentar isso para você e com essa documentação vai ser criado o código necessário, para trabalhar com essa API. Então depende da empresa que vai fornecer o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código correto é o seguinte:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    var jsonResponse = client.DownloadString(@"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<APIRestPaises>>(jsonResponse);
}
```

porque o seu retorno `json` é uma ***lista de valores*** então na linha `DeserializeObject` faça assim:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<APIRestPaises>>(jsonResponse);
```

---

ou até

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIRestPaises[]>(jsonResponse);
```

---

ou também crie uma classe assim:

```
public class Rootobject: List<APIRestPaises>
{
}
```

e no código:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonResponse);
```

isso vai representar uma lista de valores, é o que o `json` retornado representa também, e por isso do erro:

> ERRO: Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON
>   array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Projeto.ERP.Desktop.APIRestPaises'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   **array**. **JsonArrayAttribute** can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a **JSON array**.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Serializando e Desserializando objetos Json com C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168348/serializando-e-desserializando-objetos-json-com-c)
- [Deserialize JSON com Restsharp e com JavaScriptSerializer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219560/deserialize-json-com-restsharp-e-com-javascriptserializer/219627#219627)
- [Quick JSON Serialization/Deserialization in C#](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c)
- [Classe JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Resolvido @Virgilio, obrigado mais uma vez amigo. :)