# Desserializando json complexo

Tags: json

Sou novo por aqui e gostaria da ajuda voçês, preciso desserializar um json, 
para usar numa aplicação xamarin forms e estou com dificuldades, como proceder no c#? segue o json abaixo

```js
{
  "RECORDS": [{
      "Codigo": "33338",
      "Descricao": "MOLA WIL 50-1 - TRAS RURAL - 57\/64",
      "PrecoVenda": 74.75,
      "Referencia": "WIL 50-1",
      "Grupo": "002",
      "GrupoDesc": "MAM WILLYS",
      "Categoria": 3,
      "CategoriaDesc": "Material Acabado - Molas",
      "Classe": "001",
      "ClasseDesc": "MOLAS",
      "NCM": "7320.10.00"
    },
    {
      "Codigo": "33339",
      "Descricao": "MOLA WIL 50-2 - TRAS RURAL - 57\/64",
      "PrecoVenda": 69,
      "Referencia": "WIL 50-2",
      "Grupo": "002",
      "GrupoDesc": "MAM WILLYS",
      "Categoria": 3,
      "CategoriaDesc": "Material Acabado - Molas",
      "Classe": "001",
      "ClasseDesc": "MOLAS",
      "NCM": "7320.10.00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Preciso desserializar e jogar dentro de um a lista pra fazer Binding nas propriedades, método que estou utilizando, segue

```
public async void Ler()
    {
       var json = await LerArquivo.CarregarArquivo("Catalogo.json");
       var Catalogos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Catalogo>>(json);
    }
```

[image: Ao executar meu código tenho isto de retorno]

Ao executar meu código tenho isto de retorno

Comment: Troque a imagem por texto, isso facilitara alguém a te ajudar. Sempre que possível, evite imagens

Comment: Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168348/serializando-e-desserializando-objetos-json-com-c

Comment: Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219560/deserialize-json-com-restsharp-e-com-javascriptserializer/219627#219627

Answer (score 0):

Crie duas classes com o seguinte código:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public RECORD[] RECORDS { get; set; }
}

public class RECORD
{
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string PrecoVenda { get; set; }
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
    public string Grupo { get; set; }
    public string GrupoDesc { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string CategoriaDesc { get; set; }
    public string Classe { get; set; }
    public string ClasseDesc { get; set; }
    public string NCM { get; set; }
}
```

agora instale o pacote [Newtonsoft.Json - (Json.NET)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) e com essa instalação execute o seguinte código:

```
var result = Newtonsoft
            .Json
            .JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(File.ReadAllText("./data.json"));
```

nesse caso a variável `result` vai conter a lista de que precisa. Pode também fazer um ajuste no campo `PrecoVenda` mudando o seu tipo para `decimal`.

*Outros* **exemplos**:

- [Serializando e Desserializando objetos Json com C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168348/serializando-e-desserializando-objetos-json-com-c)
- [Deserialize JSON com Restsharp e com JavaScriptSerializer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219560/deserialize-json-com-restsharp-e-com-javascriptserializer/219627#219627)

Comment: o problema com o código acima é que recebo uma exceção do tipo, Unhandled Exception:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EstrelaApp.Model.Catalogo]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: @FlávioJune eu fiz de acordo com a pergunta acho que faltou passar algo. Coloque na pergunta o exemplo completo

Comment: @FlávioJune é algum campo no json com problema. Observe isso

Comment: Boa noite @Virgilio Novic, fiz de acordo com seu exemplo ainda não deu certo na variavel "json" tenho os dados porem não consigo desserializa-lo, a variavel "Catalogos é null"

Comment: Passa o json completo @FlávioJune

Comment: O json é esse mesmo o que muda é somente a quantidade de objetos contido nele, mas a estrutura é essa

Comment: @FlávioJune A SUA CLASSE Catalogo POR FAVOR

Comment: @FlávioJune você continua fazendo errado pelo visto.

Comment: @FlávioJune você fez uma classe diferente da minha resposta?